# script to send an mail if disk space capacity exceeds 90%

Tags: shell-script

I want to implement a script on my server which will automatically send email alerts if the disk usage goes over 90% . My filesystem is data/u01 and the mount point is /u01

```
#!/bin/bash

ADMIN=some1@xyz.com

ALERT=90

df -h | egrep -v 'data/u01/u01' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output; 

do

usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' )

echo $usep

if [ $usep -ge ${ALERT%} ]; then

  echo  "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep"

  df -h | mail -s "Alert: out of disk space $usep"  $ADMIN

fi

done
```

...........

but i am getting following error :

```
capacity

./iv.sh: line 8: [: capacity: integer expression expected
23%

./iv.sh: line 8: [: 23%: integer expression expected
0%
```

Comment: kindly check your code before commenting coz its also not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`-ge` expects integers. Take out the `%` after `ALERT`, and change `usep` to

```
usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | tr -d "%" )
```

Consider having a look at the monit package: it is more standard and it allows you to do more things, including taking actions based on the outcomes of monitoring.

Please consider using a more standard way of monitoring, like monit, which will allow you to do more, and is very flexible, allowing you to generate alerts and actions depending on the events in a very simple format.

Comment: here is my variant :

Comment: #!/bin/bash
       ADMIN=some1@xyz.com
      ALERT=90
          df -h | egrep -v 'data/u01/u01 | tmpfs |cdrom|Used' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output; do
             usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}'| tr -d "%" )
                   echo $usep
           if [ $usep -ge $ALERT] then
              echo  "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep"
            df -h | mail -s "Alert: out of disk space $usep"  $ADMIN
        fi
      done

Comment: ..............                    but still giving unusual error ./iv.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./iv.sh: line 10: `fi '
 i am nt able to understand

Comment: Alternatively, use `[ "${output%\%*}" -ge "$ALERT" ]"` to strip the percent and mountpoint for comparing.  Either way, please consider adding your good comment, about using a proper monitoring package, to the duplicate question; thanks.

Comment: @toby, Thanks for calling it to my attention, done.